# I want to put a jquery function inside another function

Tags: jquery, textbox

I am getting values from one textbox and putting it in another textbox. The values being transferred are a question's duration, and both textboxes use the jQuery timepicker plugin. Now this works for the first textbox but it does not work for the second textbox.  I want to include a button next to the second textbox so the user can open up the timepicker just in case the user wants to change the duration in the second textbox.

So I want to include this timepicker function below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
            timeFormat: 'hh mm ss',
            hourGrid: 4,
            minuteGrid: 10,
            secondGrid: 10,
            showOn: 'button',
            buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
        });
    });
});
```

Into the InsertQuestion(form) function below:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {
    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>");

    $('#questiondurationpicker').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $durationText = 
            $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />")
                .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
                .attr('value', $this.val())

        $duration.append($durationText);
    });

    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($duration)
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    form.questionText.value = "";
}
```

What it is suppose to do is to display the timepicker button I have created next to the "#questiondurationpickerRow" textbox so that the user can click on the button and open up the timepicker to open up the duration.

I tried to put the "questiondurationpickerRow" timepicker function in the insertQuestion(form) function but it does not display the button. Below is what I tried:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
                timeFormat: 'hh mm ss',
                hourGrid: 4,
                minuteGrid: 10,
                secondGrid: 10,
                showOn: 'button',
                buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
    });

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>");

    $('#questiondurationpicker').each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $durationText =
        $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />")
            .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
            .attr('value', $this.val())

        $duration.append($durationText);
    });

    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($duration)
    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    form.questionText.value = "";
}
```

How can I include the "questiondurationpickerRow" timepicker function in the insertQuestion(form) function so that it will display the timepicker button next to the textbox?

Comment: I do not see a reason to wrap a document ready in a document ready:`$(document).ready(function() {     $(function() {`

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {` and `$(function() {` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $(function() {
             $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
```

all you need is:

```
function insertQuestion(form) {
   $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
```

I do not see a definition

```
$tr.append($qid);
```

of $qid

an it is hard to guess what the `).trenttimepicker` does really.

EDIT:

Looking at:

```
$('#questiondurationpicker').each(function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     var $durationText =
          $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />")
             .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
             .attr('value', $this.val())
      $duration.append($durationText);
 });
```

This makes more sense (and fix syntax error)

to do as:

```
   $this = $('#questiondurationpicker');
   var $durationText = $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />")
       .attr('name', $this.attr('name'))
       .attr('value', $this.val());
   $duration.append($durationText);
```

re: missing semi-colon
only ONE element can be present with a given ID so no need for `each()` stuff

final rework:

```
var qnum = 1;

function insertQuestion(form) {
    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $duration = $("<td class='duration'></td>");

    $this = $('#questiondurationpicker');//assume this exists
    var $durationText = $("<input type='text' id='questiondurationpickerRow' readonly='readonly' />").attr('name', $this.attr('name')).attr('value', $this.val());//was issing semi colon
    $duration.append($durationText);

    $tr.append($qid);//assume $qid exists and is an element
    $tr.append($duration) $('#qandatbl').append($tr);
    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;//another assumption
    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);// assume this exists
    form.questionText.value = "";//assume this exists

    // This has to be after it gets inserted
    $('#questiondurationpickerRow').trenttimepicker({
        timeFormat: 'hh mm ss',
        hourGrid: 4,
        minuteGrid: 10,
        secondGrid: 10,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: "Images/clock.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
}
```

Here is a page with a sampe using jQuery UI datepicker:
http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/Mykd6/

Comment: its ok i have got a definition for $qid, i just did not include it in my question, i will try you answer in my code

Comment: the trenttimepicker is what i call the timepicker because there is a couple of different timepickers I am using so this differentiate between timepickers but I know this function works because it worked for the other textbox. However I tried your answer and it still does not display the button to display the timepicker next to the text box

Comment: I need the .each(function() because there are other textboxes I want to include in the code, but you have fixed the problem because you stated that the timepicker function must come after the rest of the code which is correct so you have solved the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Then your selector probably needs other ID's or selectors in it - I would suggest adding a class to all and use that as the selector since the duplicate ID note still holds.

Comment: Actually there is one more question I have found out, what this is doing is adding a new table row and in the first table row the button appears so the timepicker can be opened but if I add a second row, the button does not appear in the second row so the timepicker cannot be opened for the sceond row. Why is this?

Comment: It is the ID you add: change the ID to a class: class='questiondurationpickerRow' and then the selector: $('.questiondurationpickerRow').  As written, you can only call your function once and have it work right.